# I have an asus p5g41c l mx which requires some help in booting with nvme sad

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, uefi, nvme

I have an asus p5g41c l mx 
Please tell me if I could use an aourus rgb nvme m.2 ssd as my boot drive
I don’t think the motherboard has uefi bios

Answer (score 0):

According to the [motherboard manual](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P5G41CM_LX/HelpDesk_Manual/) and [Aorus RGB M.2 NVMe SSD](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Solid-State-Drive/AORUS-RGB-M2-NVMe-SSD-512GB/sp#sp) specs, your motherboard doesn’t support the interface *PCI-Express 3.0 x4* and *NVMe 1.3*.